# Export files to remote server using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoise-svn

I'm using TortoiseSVN to keep revisions of my code. When I commit changes, I take note of what files have changed and upload them to my server using FTP.

Here's my workflow:

1. Edit files on local computer (eg. files in C:\Users\Me\web)
2. Commit changes to local repository using rightclick-> TortoiseSVN-> SVN Commit.
3. Take the files, open FileZilla (FTP client) and upload the files to a remote server.

I was wondering if there was a way in which I could omit step 3 from my workflow. Basically I would like the changed files to be automatically uploaded to the remote server when I commit a version to the repository.

Information about my computer environment:

1. Windows 7 Ultimate x64 with TortoiseSVN x64
2. Notepad++ text editor
3. Files edited are PHP, CSS, JS, HTML, etc.
4. Server is running Linux with PHP 5.2 and MySQL.
5. FileZilla is used to upload files. I can connect to the server via SSH if that is needed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: BTW, you use **Subersion repository** to keep revisions, TortoiseSVN is just client-side GUI for interacting with repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in case of TortoiseSVN and FTP and SSH you have at least two ways (client-side hook or server-side hooks) in two workflows (export+copy or update /created/ WC on site).

[This my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13063724/960558) on similar question lists 3 server-side (svnlook uses repository at local FS) solutions, which can be used in post-commit hook on server and one TortoiseSVN-centric, interactive, client-side solution - all around "export-copy"

Comment: I've moved on to Git since this question was posted, but thank you for responding. Hopefully, other people will find your information helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this described in [Repository Replication](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication) section of SVN book. Some of them require extra programming (e.g hooks), some extra set up and configuration (e.g. `svnsync` program).